# Unsigned return type returns signed number C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm currently going through K&R C, and I got to the section on bitwise operators with this example:

```
unsigned getbits(unsigned x, int p, int n) {
  return (x >> (p + 1 - n)) & ~(~0 << n);
}
```

I've been playing around with it, and I did the following:

```
unsigned getbits(unsigned x, int p, int n) {
   return (~0 << n);
}
```

I fed in `n = 2`, and the result I got was `-4`. The result in bit form should be this (for a 32 bit integer), if I'm not mistaken: 
`1111 1111 1111 1100`
If the return type of the function wasn't unsigned, I can kind of see where the -4 would come from, but because the return type is unsigned, shouldn't this be returning an unsigned number? Why is it returning -4?

Thanks!

Comment: and how do you check it? using `%d` in printf?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, you're right - my mistake

Comment: Signed or unsigned, it's a matter of interpretation, not bit values.

Comment: The code is slightly inconsistent: `~0` is an `int`.  It would be better to write: `return (x >> (p + 1 - n)) & ~(~0U << n);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if the function declares it is returning `unsigned`, the actual use of the value after return determines how it is interpreted.

For example, `printf("%d", x);` interprets `x` as a `signed int`, even if it's declared as anything else.

Comment: using `%d` in this case just causes undefined behaviour.  C has value semantics; a function returning `unsigned` does actually return a value of type `unsigned int`.

Comment: Technically, you're correct, but wouldn't the underlying data be exactly the same in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "underlying data type?"  at the machine instruction level, data doesn't have a type itself - the type of instruction determines how it interprets the data.

Comment: I originally had `%d` and that's where the -4 came from - once I switched it to `%u` everything was fixed